# Sending variables from client to server | JSON vs POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

If I have say 1-5 variables on the client side that are needed server side and I handle my communications via ajax (Post Method) there are two major ways I can get them there.

- Using JSON to encode ( and later decode them ) and send as a JSON string in a POST variable

or

- Just create a POST variable for each variable I need to send.

Does it matter or is it just preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will definitely be an overhead for deserializing JSON, but not much. I find that JSON is far preferable to creating new variables for every value you want to send. Plus I find that once your JSON implementation is in place, scaling is much easier (ie., when you have to add new values later for whatever reason).

Answer (score 2):

I think it all boils down to the amount of overhead that json will add. If you are POSTing 2,3 or about 5 fields, then just use normal POST. Otherwise, if you are trying to send over some sizable chunk of meaningful data, its always a good idea to use JSON.

Basically for large amounts of data which needs computation at the server, its best to use JSON since decoding it will give an array of arrays and it'll just be simpler to go about it rather than cycling through the $_POST array.

In addition, encoding in JSON and sending info over to the server makes sense, especially when the server will perform computations/checks and send back some response. While doing this its always better to send responses encoded in JSON instead of plain text. Adding/editing data within the POSTED data becomes easier when using JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is only a personal preference.

I heard nothing special about performance or best practice like when using JSON with POST.
When POSTing a form from within an AJAX call I prefer using normal POST parameters unless their count is quite uncomfortable for me to write each down - then I use JSON...

But it should be uniformed per project - once You decide to use JSON, use it always...

Answer (score 1):

Well the good thing about json is the encapsulation and api it provides. But then maybe there will be a little overhead to serialize/unserialize, compared to just posting values as is.

It doesn't make a relevant difference in the end.